# How to extract arrays from a merged result set?

Tags: javascript, sql

I SQL we write (considering that #temp has all the relevant fields):

```
Select EmpId, EmpName from #temp
Select DeptId,DeptName from #temp
```

So we have two record sets - one for Employee and another for Department.

How can we do the same thing in javascript?

So far

```
function foo()
{   
    var temp = [{
      "EmpId": 1,
      "EmpName": "Michale Sharma",
      "Deptid": 4,
        "Deptname": "IT"
    }, {
      "EmpId": 2,
      "EmpName": "Sunil Das",
      "Deptid": 1,
    "Deptname": "HR"
    }
  ];

  console.log(temp);
}
```

*How to get the records pertaining to Employee and Department from temp ? So there will be two different arrays*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var employees = temp.map(function(item) {
  return {
    EmpId: item.EmpId,
    EmpName: item.EmpName
  }
});
var departments = temp.map(function(item) {
  return {
    Deptid: item.Deptid,
    Deptname: item.Deptname
  }
});
```

or

```
var employees = [], departments = [];
temp.forEach(function(item) {
  employees.push({
    EmpId: item.EmpId,
    EmpName: item.EmpName
  });
  departments.push({
    deptid: item.deptid,
    deptname: item.deptname
  });
});
```